# Two egg dropping puzzle variation: unknown/infinite floors

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, time-complexity

**Preface**

This problem was inspired by a similar question last week on SO, that got deleted before it was clear what the real question was. I think this variation makes a nice problem that I wanted to share.

**Two Egg Problem**

A detailed definition and solution can be found [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/egg-dropping/#2-eggs-k-floors), but I will add a quick summary:

*Definition*

> You are given two eggs, and access to a `k`-storey building. Both eggs
>   are identical. The aim is to find out the highest floor `f*` from which an
>   egg will not break when dropped out of a window from that floor. If an
>   egg is dropped and does not break, it is undamaged and can be dropped
>   again. However, once an egg is broken, that’s it for that egg. What is the fastes (least amount of drops) way to find `f*`?

*Solution*

The idea is to drop the first egg from floors `sqrt(k), 2*sqrt(k), 3*sqrt(k)... k`. If the egg breaks at floor `i*sqrt(k)` use the second egg to test the remaining floors between `(i-1)*sqrt(k)` and `i*sqrt(k)-1`. Overall this will result in at most `2*sqrt(k)` drops so the complexity will be `O(sqrt(k))`.

Just for completeness: there is a method with less drops in the worst-case (details can be found [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/egg-dropping/#2-eggs-k-floors)), which however has the same complexity of `O(sqrt(k))`

**The Question: Two Egg Problem with infinite/unknown floors**

Now imagine that you have no information about the number of floors `k` or `k` is infinite. Is it possible to find `f*` more efficient than just testing each floor in `O(f*)`?

In other words: Is there an *efficient* method to drop the two eggs whose runtime complexity is independent from `k` but only depends on the answer `f*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple method that has O(sqrt(f*)) complexity. Make your nth step to be n floors up, that is, check floors 1, 3 (1 + 2), 6 (1 + 2 + 3), etc. This way at the nth step you will be on n*(n+1)/2 floor, and you will reach f* in n = O(sqrt(f*)) steps.

Then for the second egg you will need to go n single steps over your last step in stage 1, which will add another O(sqrt(f*)).

If O(sqrt(k)) was optimal for known k, this method has to be optimal in terms of complexity, too.

Answer (score -1):

The sub-optimal solution for the infinite problem for two eggs is to use the sequence `1, 2^2, 3^3,... ,i^2,...` and start the second edge where the last value the first egg remains. So if the first edge remains at `n^2`, then the next one will do at most `2*n + 1 - 1` (minus 1 from the first) test to give the total of `3 * n` in the worst case with `n = sqrt(m)`.